# Trying to understand a solution to project Euler # 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>   What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ? @ http://projecteuler.net/problem=3

I have a deal going with myself that if I can't solve a project Euler problem I will understand the best solution I can find.  I did write an algorithm which worked for smaller numbers but was too inefficient to work for bigger ones.  So I googled [Zach Denton's](http://zacharydenton.com/project-euler-solutions/3/) answer and started studying it.

Here is his code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import math

def factorize(n):
    res = []
    # iterate over all even numbers first.
    while n % 2 == 0:
        res.append(2)
        n //= 2
    # try odd numbers up to sqrt(n)
    limit = math.sqrt(n+1)
    i = 3
    while i <= limit:
        if n % i == 0:
            res.append(i)
            n //= i
            limit = math.sqrt(n+i)
        else:
            i += 2
    if n != 1:
        res.append(n)
    return res

print max(factorize(600851475143))
```

Here are the bits I can't figure out for myself:

1. In the second while loop, why does he use a `sqrt(n + 1)` instead of just `sqrt(n)`?
2. Why wouldn't you also use `sqrt(n + 1)` when iterating over the even numbers in the first while loop?
3. How does the algorithm manage to find only prime factors?  In the algorithm I first wrote I had a separate test for checking whether a factor was prime, but he doesn't bother.

Comment: please post the Problem

Comment: as for point 3: any values that are *not* prime factors will have already had their own factors handled; by the time you get to `9`, `3` has already been factored out.

Answer (score 2):

1. I suspect the `+1` has to do with the imprecision of `float` (I am not sure whether it's actually required, or is simply a defensive move on the author's part).
2. The first `while` loop factors all twos out of `n`. I don't see how `sqrt(n + 1)` would fit in there.
3. If you work from small factor to large factors, you automatically eliminate all composite candidates. Think about it: once you've factored out `5`, you've automatically factored out `10`, `15`, `20` etc. No need to check whether they're prime or not: by that point `n` will not be divisible by them.

I suspect that checking for primality is what's killing your original algorithm's performance.